# Как float с буквой преобразовать в строку

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как на выводе `float` число сделать виде строки?

`toFixed` не подходит, так как числа после точки может быть разным.

нужно из "4.7e-7" сделать "0.00000047"

```js
let num = [
  0.00000047.toString(),
  0.00000047.toFixed(8), // не подходит, так как неизвестно количество цифр
];

console.log(num);
```

Comment: Какая-то непростая тема, судя по всему )  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661562/how-to-format-a-float-in-javascript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685680/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers-in-javascript

Comment: @splash58 `BigInt(0.00000047).toString()` то что там предлагается выдает ошибку

Comment: вот этот ответ  https://stackoverflow.com/a/61281355/4804629

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запись числа "с буквой" называется экспоненциальной.

> *a*e<sup>*b*</sup> === *a* * 10<sup>*b*</sup>

```js
let num = [
  0.00000047.toString(),
  0.00000047.toFixed(8), // не подходит, так как неизвестно количество цифр
  stupidStrReplace(0.00000047),  // функция принимает число и как number...
  stupidStrReplace('4.7e-7'),    // ...и как string (только в виде '123', '1.23', '123.', '.23', '1.23e4', или '.23e4')
];
console.log(num);

function stupidStrReplace(n) {
  let [mnts, exp] = String(n).split(/e/i);
  if (!isFinite(+mnts)) return NaN;
  if (!(exp = +exp)) return mnts;
  const [int = '0', dec = ''] = mnts.split('.');
  return (exp > 0)
    ? int + dec.padEnd(exp, '0')
    : '0.' + int.padStart(Math.abs(exp), '0') + dec;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

получаем число (leftPart) и степень, в которую нужно подносить 10 (rightPart) + форматируем вывод

```js
const str = '4.7e-7';
const eIndex = str.indexOf('e');
const leftPart = parseFloat(str.slice(0, eIndex));    // 4.7
const rightPart = parseInt(str.slice(eIndex + 1));    // -7
let result = leftPart * Math.pow(10, rightPart);
if (rightPart < 0) {
    result = result.toFixed(Math.abs(rightPart) + 1);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: вместо indexOf и двух slice можно использовать один split по `e`